# Configuring Apache 2.4 on Fedora 23

Tags: localhost, apache2.4, cgi-bin, fedora-23

I have got problems with apache 2.4 on Fedora. When on Debian I do

> service apache2 start

I can access this machine from another computer just by 
typing it's IP address on browser., but on Fedora I can't.
And second problem is I can't access on Fedora itself directory localhost/cgi-bin/ It says

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/ on this server.

I know that problem with httpd.conf file (mine is on default state), I read few answers on Stack
but didn't understand them. Please help!

Comment: Are you on Fedora Workstation, Fedora Server, or something else? It makes a difference because the firewall config is different.

Comment: Also, where is the directory `localhost/cgi-bin` on your filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 23 start Apache like this (as root)

```
$ systemctl start httpd
```

check if started

```
$ systemctl status httpd
```

to make it start by default:

```
$ systemctl enable httpd.service
```